# how to run an MPI example in PARPACK

Tags: mpi, arpack

I am able to compile `psndrv1.f`, which is an example in `ARPACK/PARPACK/EXAMPLE/MPI` folder.  However, when I run the program with the command `mpirun -np 4 a.out`, I got the following error.

```
[.th:9951] *** An error occurred in MPI_Allreduce
[.th:9951] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[.th:9951] *** MPI_ERR_OP: invalid reduce operation
[.th:9951] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 9951 on
node superinfra.ku.ac.th exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could oc
cur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[.th:09950] 3 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-err
ors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[.th:09950] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to
 see all help / error messages
```

I'm using a rock cluster.  Please help.

Comment: From the error message it looks like it is using a wrong/invalid operation for `MPI_Allreduce`. Can you find out what operation it is passing there? Also, putting the code in your question would help - it is actually encouraged by SO.

Comment: The [version of the] MPI implmentation used to compile the code or against which the PARPACK library is linked differs from the one that `mpirun` comes from.

Comment: @xeroqu The code I'm compiling is ARPACK.  It is written by someone else.  It contains a lot of files.  I don't know what code to show.

Comment: @HristoIliev Thank you for the idea.  I tried to run with different mpi.  They all fails but some with different error messages.

Comment: I would recommend that you clean the entire project and rebuild everything from scratch while making sure that only one version of MPI is used throughout the process. In general, having multiple MPI implementations or versions of the same MPI library installed is a Bad Idea™ unless done properly. If ARPACK comes precompiled, make sure that you use exactly the same MPI implementation and version for building and running the examples.

Comment: @HristoIliev I'm building from scratch using mpif90.  I don't know which mpi is compatible with that compiler or PARPACK.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a completely same problem today and managed to solve it. I want to share what troubled me in case anyone could get stuck in the same trap. It was a mismatch between the mpi library I use to compile and the "mpif.h" files which PARPACK package includes.

According to my observation, PARPACK package has 3 mpif.h files. My solution is to replace all of the "mpif.h" files in the PARPACK directory tree with my mpi library's "mpif.h" filles.